# Jolt Transformation to move an attribute in each element of the array

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

My Json Input is as follows

```json
{
  "ref": "22",
  "id": "177",
  "table": [
    {
      "zn": 1,
      "stfflbisart": 10
    },
    {
      "zn": 2,
      "stfflbisart": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want the ref field to be included in every element present in the array object

And my desired output is as below:

```json
{
  "id": "177",
  "table": [
    {
      "zn": 1,
      "stfflbisart": 10,
      "ref": "22"
    },
    {
      "zn": 2,
      "stfflbisart": 50,
      "ref": "22"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Jolt spec what I tried wasn't working out.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ref": "ref",
      "table": {
        "*": {
          // simple match.  Put the value '4' in the output under the "Rating" field
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Any help is much appreciated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such a **shift** operation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "table": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[&1].&",
          "@(2,ref)": "&2.[&1].ref"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- ampersand(`&`)s at the at end( appearing as leaves ) match
  substitutions for the keys where no need to repeat their names
- array names followed by dots (`table.`) might also be replaced with
  another name such as `tab.` in order to rename the current array
- those arrays are followed by  `.[&1]` ( eg. `table.[&1]` ) in order
  to represent combining those key-value pairs into json objects while
  nesting them as elements for the array
- `"*"` nested following `"table": { "*": {` represents all keys of
  the `table` array